# Input function & Symbol?

Tags: c++

My friend showed me this code and asked me what is the `&` sign in the input parameter?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int & i, int j) {
    i++;
    j++;
}

int main() {
    int i=1, j=2;
    f(i, j);
    cout << ( i + j );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "p.s no real programmer would include an & sign!" - WTF?!?

Comment: what is the & sign for? why do it?

Comment: I beg your pardon.  I am a real programmer and I use the `&` token daily.

Comment: Real programmers write object files directly. They don't care about such nuisances as programming languages not to say &.

Comment: @vitaut: ... with butterflies!

Comment: & adds spicyness to the function... but real programmers eat it raw

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running it?  Does it output what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` in `f()` is a [reference parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Reference parameter.

Answer (score 3):

It means the parameter is [passed by reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr233.htm), and may be altered in the calling code by actions performed inside of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a pretty typical "do you understand references" question.   the `&` means that `i` is passed to the function by reference.  In this example, the net effect is that any changes you make to `i` in the function `f` are carried back to the calling function.

So, in this example, the program would output `4`.  If `i` had been passed by value instead, it would output `3` and if both `i` and `j` were passed by reference, it would output `5`.